# Question recommendation algorithm in StackExchange

Tags: discussion

I am trying to understand how StackExchange recommends questions to the users.

Untill now, my observation is *tags* of  recommended questions are associated with *tags* user is related to (tags of questions / answers he posted and likes). However, what might be the underlying **algorithm** of question recommendation in StackExchange?

What might be an appropriate algorithm(collaborative filtering or content-based filtering) for a general question recommendation problem?

PS:
The recommended question list refers to:

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell us what you mean by "recommend"? (I am not familiar with any SE mechanisms that offer or present questions apart from the usual options to sort and search.)

Comment: I believe the OP is asking where the list of "Related" questions (seen to the right $\rightarrow$) comes from, & probably even more specifically where the list of possible related threads that appears between your title & the body of your Q when you are typing your question in the first place (ie, the "Questions that may already have your answer") comes from.

Comment: Here's a possible meta.SO thread to explore: [What does SO use to find "Questions that may already have your answer"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167281/) I believe there is another thread somewhere I've seen that explicitly explains the search algorithm used (IIRC, it's something like a simple search on the keywords in your title), but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the question list appearing when you enter stackoverflow.com in the browser.

Comment: It's a bit weird that they call them "interesting" on SO. Here on CV, they're called "active", which provides a more accurate connotation. These are just the questions that were most recently asked or answered ( / edited, etc).

Comment: But actually, they are recommended (at least for SO)in the sense that questions are being filtered according to my favourite tags. Also what I have asked/answered/upvoted have some influence on what is being recommended.

Comment: OK, maybe I'm getting closer to your question. You want to know about how some of the questions are highlighted in a different color. This is based on the tags those questions have. You can select tags to be highlighted by clicking on `edit` next to "Favorite Tags" & likewise you can select tags to be ignored. If you don't want any tags highlighted, edit your favorite tags & add something that isn't a tag name (on CV I have `[jkjkjkjkjk]` so that nothing is highlighted, but on SO, I only look at R Q's so the highlighting is helpful to me).

Comment: I didn't find any info on the algorithm used to determine what your 'favorite' tags probably would be if you had entered them yourself, but there is some more info on these topics here: [what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/), here: [please-let-users-opt-out-of-the-frequented-tag-system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88345/), & [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics).

Comment: No, I mean something else. Actually, there *might* be some advanced mechanism driving the question recommendation. Questions you asked, answers you provided, even Q&A you voted might be considered when building a "interested topics" profile for you, which is used to recommend questions. Whether the technique used in question recommendation is collaborative filtering or keyword based filtering is unknown. However, what I am more certain is that tags play an important role in this process.

Comment: And I don't think it is a meta question. It is about recommendation algorithm so it should be migrated to somewhere else.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about machine learning algorithm

Comment: Based on these comments, I'm still confused about what it is you want to know. Are you trying to find out the machine learning algorithm that SE uses to determine what your 'favorite' tags would be, if you don't enter any on your own? That Q might be appropriate for meta.SO. FWIW, I don't know exactly, but I do know it is based only on tags. (Also, fortunately I keep checking back here, but if you want me to be alerted that you have left me a comment, you need to include `@gung` in your comment.)